# OSMdroid Strange NoSuchMethodError when placing marker

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid, nosuchmethoderror

I'm building a basic osmdroid android application but i'm getting a strange error when trying to place a marker that I can't figure out. It seems to be something to do with getting the geopoint location

 I'm getting the following come up in logcat:

```
06-30 12:29:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(28118): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint.clone
06-30 12:29:43.124: E/AndroidRuntime(28118):    at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.Marker.setPosition(Marker.java:123)
```

Has anyone come across this before? or something similar?

Comment: which android version are you using, when the error occurs? is there any obfuscator in you build process? have you looked into the sdk-android.jar if Object.clone() is supportet? I had a similar issue with some library that claims to be android-8 (2.2) compatible but uses standard-java-api calls that are not supported yet on android-8

Comment: android 4.3. the strange thing about it all is that i've created applications in the past to do the same thing but i've had no problems placing markers ever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of osmdroid, and which version of OSMBonusPack are you using? 
They **must** be compatible. 
Refer to OSMBonusPack [How to include](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/HowToInclude) page.

Comment: i'm using osmdroid 3.0.5 and osmbonuspack 4.3

Comment: just included a newer version of osmdroid and it now works! absolutely kicking myselfm i've wasted a whole day of work on this problem, thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction!! :D